# function styleCheckbox() in jqgrid from ace doesn't work perfectly

Tags: checkbox, jqgrid, styles

I copied [jqgrid.html](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0B30DGR) from ace demo, and activated function `styleCheckbox()` to change the style of multiselecting checkboxs, but something got wrong. The checkbox didn't change when I clicked the square, while it worked normally when I clicked other areas of the row.

the definition of function styelCheckbox():

```
function styleCheckbox(table) {
    $(table).find('input:checkbox').addClass('ace')
            .wrap('<label />')
            .after('<span class="lbl align-top" />')
            .removeClass('cbox');

    $('.ui-jqgrid-labels th[id*="_cb"]:first-child')
            .find('input.cbox[type=checkbox]').addClass('ace')
            .wrap('<label />').after('<span class="lbl align-top" />')
            .removeClass('cbox');
}
```

called after jqgrid loaded completely:

```
loadComplete : function() {
    var table = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        styleCheckbox(table);
    }, 0);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution at [Checkbox & Switch](http://Sometimes%20you%20shouldn't%20wrap%20the%20checkbox%20and%20.lbl%20inside%20a%20label.%20%20For%20example%20in%20jqGrid%20plugin,%20when%20you%20launch%20an%20%22edit%20record%22%20or%20%22new%20record%22%20dialog,%20and%20want%20to%20style%20the%20checkbox%20dynamically:%20%20%20form.find('input[type=checkbox]')%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.addClass('ace%20ace-switch%20ace-switch-5').after('%3Cspan%20class=%22lbl%22%3E%3C/span%3E');%20Checkbox%20should%20not%20be%20wrapped%20inside%20label%20because%20it%20conflicts%20with%20plugin's%20data%20upload%20mechanism.)(see the Notes):

> Sometimes you shouldn't wrap the checkbox and .lbl inside a label. 
>   For example in jqGrid plugin, when you launch an "edit record" or "new record" dialog, and want to style the checkbox dynamically:
>     form.find('input[type=checkbox]')
>         .addClass('ace ace-switch ace-switch-5').after('');
>   Checkbox should not be wrapped inside label because it conflicts with plugin's data upload mechanism.

So I delete the `.wrap(<label />)` in function `styleCheckbox()`, then It worked perfectly as I wanted.

Modified code:

```
function styleCheckbox(table) {
$(table).find('input:checkbox').addClass('ace')
        .after('<span class="lbl align-top" />')
        .removeClass('cbox');

        $('.ui-jqgrid-labels th[id*="_cb"]:first-child')
        .find('input.cbox[type=checkbox]').addClass('ace')
        .after('<span class="lbl align-top" />')
        .removeClass('cbox');
```

}